# NAudio WASAPI recording device with more then 2 channels throws unsupported format error

Tags: c#, naudio, wasapi

I faced a problem with recording WASAPI loopback device having 6 or 8 channels using NAdio library.
E.g. Device has following wave format: *32 bit PCM: 44kHz 6 channels wBitsPerSample:32*

```
public MMDevice Device;
private WasapiCapture _waveIn;

...

_waveIn = IsLoopback ? new WasapiLoopbackCapture(Device) : new WasapiCapture(Device);
_waveIn.DataAvailable += OnDataAvailable;
_waveIn.RecordingStopped += OnRecordingStopped;
_waveIn.StartRecording();
```

It crashes on *StartRecording* with *"Unsupported Wave Format"* error
Error is coming from WasapiCapture.InitializeCaptureDevice() while it calls

```
if (!audioClient.IsFormatSupported(ShareMode, WaveFormat))
    throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported Wave Format");
```

The code works fine if I switch device to 2 channel using windows->control panel_>Sound settings
Is there any walk around this problem? Can I somehow change Device mixformat on the fly

Comment: Hmm. Never seen 6 channels on a recording device before. Have you tried any other libraries?

Comment: As I mentioned I recording loopback device. So it's actually sound from speakers 5.1 (5 channels plus subwoofer channel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is happening. There is a constructor of WasapiCapture class in NAudio library

```
public WasapiCapture(MMDevice captureDevice)
{
     syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
     audioClient = captureDevice.AudioClient;
     ShareMode = AudioClientShareMode.Shared;
     waveFormat = audioClient.MixFormat;

     if (waveFormat is WaveFormatExtensible wfe)
         try
         {
             waveFormat = wfe.ToStandardWaveFormat();
         }
         catch (InvalidOperationException)
         {
             // couldn't convert to a standard format
         }
}
```

It is using WaveFormat.ToStandardWaveFormat(). I tried to comment out part which changes format to standard one

```
// if (waveFormat is WaveFormatExtensible wfe)
//     try
//     {
//         waveFormat = wfe.ToStandardWaveFormat();
//     }
//     catch (InvalidOperationException)
//     {
//         // couldn't convert to a standard format
//     }
```

In my case I just leaving original [NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatExtensible] = {32 bit PCM: 44kHz 6 channels wBitsPerSample:32 dwChannelMask:1551 subFormat:00000003-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71 extraSize:22}

Now WasapiCapture.InitializeCaptureDevice() is running successfully and I'm getting data.

- I created MyWasapiCapture class which is copy of original WasapiCapture except am code commented out
- saving data to buffer as it is
- passing it through NAudio.Wave.MediaFoundationResampler, which allow to resample and change number of channels. At the end I have format I need with number of channels I need.